# Why do I get these errors?

Tags: java, android

These are the errors:

`The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type HomeFragment` -Line 27

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HomeFragment must override or implement a supertype method` -Line 29

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HomeFragment must override or implement a supertype method` -Line 25

All of these are on my `HomeFragment.java`

```
package com.colourity.snatsh;

import com.colourity.snatsh.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.colourity.snatsh.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.colourity.snatsh.model.NavDrawerItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

This occurs when I try to have action bar icons on `HomeFragment` , instead of `MainActivity`. I'm new so take it easy on me. Any help would be great. And a solution would be good.

**Edit**

My updated code:

```
    package com.colourity.snatsh;

import com.colourity.snatsh.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater1 = getMenuInflater();
        inflater1.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return;
    }

    private MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   



}
```

Comment: ... Now, show your updated code.

Comment: Not sure if it's correct but it's under updated. @shree202

Comment: If you are trying to add ActionBar in your activity checkout this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I already have an action bar. I'm just trying to have different icon buttons for each fragment. Since when I put them in my `MainActivity` they show up on all activities. @shree202

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Fragments cannot have an action bar, only Activities can.

Longer Answer: The `Fragment` class does not contain any of the methods which you are trying to use or override. These are all methods of the `Activity` class. For more information about what methods are available in each class, I strongly suggest that you become intimately familiar with [the Android developer guides](http://developer.android.com/index.html). In particular, you can use the docs for [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) to learn about what methods are in each of these classes.

Long Answer: Fragments can add menu items to the `ActionBar` which is maintained by the containing `Activity`. To do so, you must override [`onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater%29). Notice how this signature differs from [`onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) from `Activity`.

Comment: Action bar icons? But then how does Kik do it  http://imgur.com/jIdhlBu,FzOhJzN#0 http://imgur.com/jIdhlBu,FzOhJzN#1

Comment: And then how would I incorporate it with navigation drawer? Since they use fragments

Comment: I changed it to this `@Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` But I still get errors

Comment: @user3342131 Note that you the inflater is passed as a parameter. You don't need to call `getInflater()` to get it. After you fix that, if you still get errors, please edit your original question or ask a new question with the modified code and error messages.